# VBA for changing multiple cell formats - stop values from repeating

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

A [previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38251184/vba-for-replacing-format-but-preserving-cell-value) I posed to the group was solved thanks to [Vincent G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5350831/vincent-g)'s help.

To summarize, I have written some VBA which identifies cells formatted general like "<0" (with the symbol "<" as part of the cell value), and the VBA will change the format to a numerical format (with the "<" as part of the format) with the same number of decimal places as the original value (e.g., "<0.564" general will be changed to "< 0.564" numerical).

This code worked on a small set of test data, but when scaling up, I have run into another problem: with multiple instances of cells with teh same number of decimal places, the VBA works as intended for custom formats "< 0.0" through "< 0.00000", but for some reason it copies the same value for the first instance of "<0" it encounters into all other instances of this formatting.

It's a little painful to describe so please check out [my example spreadsheet on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lbpfb1s3rj28hhn/Formatting%20VBA.xlsm?dl=0): the sheet has test data, the VBA, and a description of the issue.

Many thanks for your time and expertise,
Christian

Comment: Screenshots of data and the sections of code you're having problems with will go a long way toward getting a good answer.  There aren't that many people here who will open random macro enabled workbooks downloaded from Dropbox.

Comment: Thanks Comintern, that is good advice I will follow in my next post.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow exactly what you're doing in that code of yours, but here's how I've done this in the past.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("A2:A25")
        ModifyCellNumberFormat c
    Next c

End Sub

'Modify the format of a cell to include any modifier
Sub ModifyCellNumberFormat(c As Range)

    Dim sModifierFormat As String, strVal As String, dotPos As Integer
    Dim modifier As String

    strVal = Trim(CStr(c.Value))

    If strVal Like "<*" Or strVal Like ">*" Then
        modifier = Left(strVal, 1)
        strVal = Trim(Right(strVal, Len(strVal) - 1))
        dotPos = InStr(strVal, ".")
        'construct the numeric part of the format string (eg. "0.000")
        If dotPos = 0 Then
            sModifierFormat = "0" 'no d.p., so simple format is OK
        Else
            sModifierFormat = "0." & String(Len(strVal) - dotPos, "0")
        End If
        c.Value = strVal
        c.NumberFormat = modifier & sModifierFormat 'add format to value cell
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, have to admit that I also do not follow what you're doing in this code of yours, but for _very_ different reasons! :) That is succinct and very effective, thanks! If I wanted the output format to include a space following the <, would I be adding something to the 3rd to last line: "c.NumberFormat = modifier & sModifierFormat"?

Answer (score 0):

Using @Jeeped solution to the last problem you could just do something like this. Probably could be made a bit more robust (trimming c.value before doing checks and such) but it should do what you want.

```
Sub test()

For Each c In Sheet1.Range("A2:A25")
    If Left(c.Value, 1) = "<" Then
        c.Value = Right(c.Value, Len(c.Value) - 1)
        c.NumberFormat = "[>1]< 0;[>0]< 0.0####; 0; @"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Even more succinct! I really appreciate the help, clearly out of my depth with this request. I will test and employ.